# Not able to use com.googlecode.sardine in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, mule, webdav, sardine

I am not able to build maven project in mule

I'm getting an error. Although I have `googlecode.sardine` jar in repository:

```
[ERROR] /D:/.../src/main/java/com/download/filesdownload.java:[8,30] package com.googlecode.sardine does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/.../src/main/java/com/download/filesdownload.java:[9,30] package com.googlecode.sardine does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/.../src/main/java/com/download/filesdownload.java:[10,30] package com.googlecode.sardine does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/.../src/main/java/com/download/filesdownload.java:[8,30] package com.googlecode.sardine does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/.../src/main/java/com/download/filesdownload.java:[9,30] package com.googlecode.sardine does not exist
```

Comment: Sardine WEBDAV client?

Comment: yes Sardine webdav client

Comment: Yu could get it from Maven: groupId="com.github.lookfirst" artifactid="sardine" version="5.4"

Comment: Add the `sardine` dependancy to the `pom.xml` file in your project's root directory.

Comment: I have added the dependecny but still it is not working